# Как узнать, какое приложение было запущено?

Tags: android

Можно ли как-то отловить(например, Приёмником), что было запущено такое-то приложение, либо закрыто такое-то приложение, либо открыто такое-то приложение с такой-то Активности? Возможно есть системные Intent-ы? Как крайний вариант можно парсить logcat. Там есть некоторая информация от ActivityManager:

```
Process com.DefiantDev.SkiSafari (pid 21119) has died.
START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=ru.imholynx.simplecase/.MainActivity (has  extras)} from pid 21366
```

Но если вы знаете более простой вариант, буду благодарен, если расскажете.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд лучшее решение парсить логкат
вот интересная дискуссия на эту тему. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290936/android-detect-when-other-apps-are-launched

Comment: Мда, судя по той дискуссии, это единственный вариант. И тем более совершенно не идеальный, так как вывод ActionManager отличается в зависимости от версии Android и устройства.